# Write text only if Execute Metadata is not empty

Tags: conditionals, catchfile

I use the `catchfilebetweentags` package to get specific content from a common `.tex` file. MWE for the file where all content is stored (called `master.tex`):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.5in, right=1.5in,footskip=0in]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.14in}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Past exam questions}
\rhead{Database}


%<*18mj-43-2-5>

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*$)$, rightmargin=0.05\linewidth, leftmargin=0.05\linewidth]
    \item Explain why the concept of the margin is significant in the economic theory of consumer behaviour. [12]
    \item Discuss whether the calculation of a marginal cost or an average cost is more significant in reaching conclusions about economic efficiency. [13]
\end{enumerate}

%</18mj-43-2-5>

\end{document}
```

Note that this document is tagged as `18mj-43-2-1`. The `-5` at the end is an identifier for question-type. **This question is a type 5**.

---

MWE for the document which outputs type-1 questions (called `type1.tex`):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.5in, right=1.5in,footskip=0in]{geometry}

\def\i{May/June 2017, QP 43, Q2}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.14in}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Past exam questions}
\rhead{Topic 1}


This line should execute only if the Execute Metadata is not empty.

\ExecuteMetaData[master.tex]{18mj-43-2-1}

This line should execute regardless.


\end{document}
```

I'd like for the line of text above the `\ExecuteMetaData` to be conditional; run only if there is output returned by the command. In the example here, there will be no output from the `\ExecuteMetaData` (since this document is displaying type 1 questions only).

How can this be achieved?

Comment: I'm confused! In `master.tex` should be the tags be the same, so either `<*18mj-43-2-1>...</18mj-43-2-1>` or `<*18mj-43-2-5>...</18mj-43-2-5>`? By my reading of the `catchfilebetweentags` you need the same opening and ending tags for `\ExecuteMetaData`. As a result, your MWE does not compile.

Comment: @Andrew Apologies for the typo, I've edited it.

Comment: Actually @Andrew , it's fine. I've realised that a sufficient work-around is to find a way to include what I want within the tags in `master`.

Comment: I just read your final comment. Is the question still open or is it solved by @Andrew's comment?

Comment: @marmot I've left it open in case anyone has a good way to do it. I've found a separate workaround, which is just putting the line `This line should execute only if the Execute Metadata is not empty.` into the `master.tex` file.